# Always have to type 'sudo service ssh restart' on raspberry pi for controlling through laptop using putty

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, putty, raspbian

I am using my laptop's screen, keyboard and mouse for using raspberry pi 3 by using putty. but putty doesn't connect till I run 'sudo service ssh restart' command from terminal for which at least a keyboard is required which kinda defies the purpose. Is there any way to solve this or maybe I could put that command somewhere in the s card which has the os so that the command runs automatically at startup?

Comment: enable it at startup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup#9388 in your case `sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults`

Comment: OK. Thank you. Is there any way I could do that from modifying or adding any file on the sd card since i don't currently have a usb keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't connect an keyboard try this, mount the SD card in another system and create symbolink links like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc2.d/s03ssh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc3.d/s03ssh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc4.d/s03ssh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc5.d/s03ssh
```

then restart and check the ssh connection